# DatagridComboBoxColumn not displaying value

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having some difficulty with the `comboboxcolumn` within a data grid, I want the value that's displayed and edited taken from the data object used by the rest of the data grid and the values for the drop down list taken from another data object. I've got the `combobox` `dropdown` list to work but I'm having difficulty getting it to show the value from the data grid row context.

Here's my layout

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Sheet date:</Label>
        <DatePicker/>     
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="gridTimesheets" Height="205" Margin="4, 4, 4, 0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="No." Width="40" Binding="{Binding ItemNumber }"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" Header="WorksorderID" x:Name="worksorderColumn"                       
            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=WorksorderID}"  SelectedValuePath="WorksorderID"
             DisplayMemberPath="WONA">                   
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time On" Width="60" Binding="{Binding TimeOn}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time Off" Width="60" Binding="{Binding TimeOff}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Duration" Width="65" Binding="{Binding Duration}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete" x:Name="btnDelete"
                             Click="btnDelete_Click"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Add" Margin="4, 4, 4, 0" Click="btnAdd_Click"></Button>
    <Button Content="Export" Margin="4, 4, 4, 4" ></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's my code

```
namespace Timesheet
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    TimesheetDatabase.TimesheetDB timesheetdb = new TimesheetDatabase.TimesheetDB();
    EFACSDatabase.EFACSDB efacsdb = new EFACSDatabase.EFACSDB();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridTimesheets.ItemsSource = timesheetdb.GetTimesheetItems();
        worksorderColumn.ItemsSource = efacsdb.GetOrderItems();

    }
```

OrderItem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace EFACSDatabase
{
public class OrderItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string orderid;
    public string OrderID
    {
        get { return orderid; }
        set
        {
            orderid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OrderID"));
        }
    }

    private string wona;
    public string WONA
    {
        get { return wona; }
        set
        {
            wona = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("WONA"));
        }
    }

    private string partid;

    public string PartID
    {
        get { return partid; }
        set
        {
            partid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PartID"));
        }
    }

    private string customer;
    public string Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set
        {
            customer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Customer"));
        }
    }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Description"));
        }

    }

     public OrderItem(string orderid, string wona, string partid, string customer, string description)
    {
        OrderID = orderid;
        WONA = wona;
        PartID = partid;
        Customer = customer;
        Description = description;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
}
```

TimesheetItem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TimesheetDatabase
{
public class TimesheetItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int timesheetitemid;
    public int TimesheetItemID
    {
        get { return timesheetitemid; }
        set
        {
            timesheetitemid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimesheetItemID"));
        }
    }

    private int timesheetid;
    public int TimesheetID
    {
        get { return timesheetid; }
        set
        {
            timesheetid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimesheetID"));
        }
    }

    private int itemnumber;
    public int ItemNumber
    {
        get { return itemnumber; }
        set
        {
            itemnumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemNumber"));
        }
    }



    private TimeSpan timeon;
    public TimeSpan TimeOn
    {
        get { return timeon; }
        set
        {
            timeon = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeOn"));
        }
    }

    private TimeSpan timeoff;
    public TimeSpan TimeOff
    {
        get { return timeoff; }
        set
        {
            timeoff = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeOff"));
        }
    }
    private String worksorderid;
    public String WorksorderID
    {
         get { return worksorderid; }
         set
         {
             worksorderid = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("WorksorderID"));
         }
     }


    private double duration;
    public double Duration
    {
        get { return duration; }
        set
        {
            duration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Duration"));
        }    
    }

    public TimesheetItem(int timesheetitemid, int timesheetid, int itemnumber, TimeSpan timeon, TimeSpan timeoff, String worksorderid, double duration)
    {
        TimesheetItemID = timesheetitemid;
        TimesheetID = timesheetid;
        ItemNumber = itemnumber;
        TimeOn = timeon;
        TimeOff = timeoff;
        WorksorderID = worksorderid;
        Duration = duration;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to get the `combobox` to display a value from `GetTimesheetItems` and allow the user to change that value from the drop down using values from `GetOrderItems`.

Comment: Your code is comparing row's WorksorderID with comboBox's WONA. better you change the selectedValuePath to WorksorderID(should be the property of itemsSource of the dropdown)

Comment: Ok I've change that, its still not display the value. Thanks for your help

Comment: Since comboBox itemssource is OrderItems, the selectedValuePath should be OrderID & then you want to map OrderId to Row's WorksorderID ,so SelectedValueBinding should be done for WorksorderID. just change the selectedValuePath & inform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I’m not sure what you mean. I’m querying an ERP systems database to retrieve the active worksorders in the system. I merely want to display the available worksorders in the drop down so the user can select from the list and populate the field with that ID. WONA stands for worksorderid I just called it that to differentiate between worksorderid in TimesheetItem.

Comment: so each TimeSheetItem is a row with wrkOrderId & the combobox has orderItems, the value selected in the dropdown should be the matching WONA for wrkOrderId. correct !

Comment: SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=WorksorderID}"  SelectedValuePath="WONA" DisplayMemberPath="WONA"

Comment: what do you see when you click on the dropdown- empty fields or no items at all.

Comment: When you click on the combo box the list of works orders is displayed its just the worksorderid stored TimesheetItem I can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" 
                        Header="WorksorderID" 
                        x:Name="worksorderColumn"                       
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=WorksorderID}"
                        SelectedValuePath="WONA"
                        DisplayMemberPath="WONA">                   
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

- The `SelectedValueBinding` is bound to the `WorksorderID` property of the `TimesheetItem` object, which is the item of the `DataGrid`. This means that when you select one item from the combo, its value (determined by `SelectedValuePath`) will be assigned to the `WorksorderID` property of the DataGrid item.
- The `SelectedValuePath` is set to the `WONA` property of the `OrderItem` object selected on the `ComboBox`. This indicates that the value of each item in the combo is determined by its `WONA` property, that according to you, corresponds to the WorksorderID...
- And similarly, the `DisplayMemberPath` is set to the `WONA` property of the `OrderItem` objects contained on the `ComboBox` drop-down list. This just selects the property you wish to visualize inside the combo, for each item.

**EDIT:** If you have problems with the combos being empty in the initial load, then invert the order on which you're loading the items. I mean, first load the items of the ComboBoxColumn, and then the items of the DataGrid.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    worksorderColumn.ItemsSource = efacsdb.GetOrderItems();
    gridTimesheets.ItemsSource = timesheetdb.GetTimesheetItems();
}
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. Now instead of storing the WorksorderID its storing the OrderID. The combo box works, selecting a value works and selecting a value is written back. The problem I having is when initially load the data grid the value is works order isn't displayed until you change it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to use the `WONA` property instead of the `OrderID`. I've also added a suggestion for your problem with the combos not being loaded initally: just load the items of the combos first, before you load the items of the DataGrid.

Comment: Thats worked it was the order I was loading my items, Thanks!